# fetch single record using PHP PDO and return result

Tags: php, pdo

how to fetch single row with all columns in custom php function and return result

here is my custom function code

```
function getdata($sql,$dbh)
 {

    $result=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $res=$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   // var_dump($res);
    return $res; 
 }
```

not working ...?

Comment: `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, and a tip for your next question: **USE GOOGLE**!

Comment: And you're not executing your statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest you to change this approach a bit, to make it A LOT more flexible.

- First, you definitely have to make this function **accept an array with data for execute()**. Otherwise there will be no sense in using prepare or PDO at all.
- Then, make your function return the statement. It will make it enormously flexible

So, change the code to this

```
function getdata($dbh, $sql, $params = NULL)
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params)
    return $stmt; 
}
```

this way you'll be able to fetch either single record.

```
$row = getdata($dbh, $sql)->fetch();
```

or multiple rows

```
$row = getdata($dbh, $sql)->fetchAll();
```

or even run insert or update queries from which you cannot fetch at all.

Comment: it shouldn't be, as there is a default set, `$params = NULL` - so it can go without 3rd parameter

Answer (score 2):

You are not executing your Query?!

```
$dbh = new PDO("connection string"); 
$get_row = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$get_row->execute(); 
$row = $get_row->fetch();
```

Try this for get Single Row of all column.